# How to format the Y axis values on Rickshaw Graphs

Tags: charts, d3.js, rickshaw

I want to use the Javascript graphs of
    http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/

and I got it working for one exception, when my values of less than 0.00000100 then the y-axis values are shown in scientific format, e.g.  2e-7  for the value 0.00000020

How to I make it show 0.00000020 instead of 2e-7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used rickshaw, but looking at this example on the homepage page:

```
var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
        graph: graph,
        orientation: 'left',
        tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
        element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
} );
```

It looks like you can pass a function to tickFormat. In this case [formatKMBT](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.js) is passed, and it looks like this:

```
Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT = function(y) {
    var abs_y = Math.abs(y);
    if (abs_y >= 1000000000000)   { return y / 1000000000000 + "T" }
    else if (abs_y >= 1000000000) { return y / 1000000000 + "B" }
    else if (abs_y >= 1000000)    { return y / 1000000 + "M" }
    else if (abs_y >= 1000)       { return y / 1000 + "K" } 
    ...ect
```

From here, you can use d3 built in [number formatters](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting) or roll your own. For example:

```
function yAxisFormat(d){ return d.toFixed(8); }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:

```
var yAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
            graph: graph,
            tickFormat: function(y){return y.toPrecision(3)}
        } );
```

You can put whatever function you want there.